# Creating a sub directory and storing files

Tags: r

How do I set my path in my script So I don't have to navigate into that folder to run the .csv files and How do I create a folder example "code_coverage_png" from the png files that I created?

The .csv files are located in a folder called "codecov".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)






setwd(paste(getwd(),"codecov",sep="/"))
csv_list = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
print(csv_list)

png_csv_path= (paste(getwd(),"codecov_png",sep="/"))
dir.create(png_csv_path)
print(png_csv_path)


for(i in 1:length(csv_list)){

  data_frame <-read.csv(csv_list[i], header =  TRUE)
  data_frame$dayDifference <- as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]","",data_frame$dayDifference))
  #if(names(data_frame) %in% "dayDifference"){data_frame$dayDifference <- as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]","",data_frame$dayDifference))}
  print(data_frame$dayDifference)
  print(csv_list[i])
  gg <- ggplot(data = data_frame , mapping = aes(x = covpercent, y = dayDifference)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(data_frame$dayDifference))) +
    labs(x = "Code coverage",
         y = "Number of days between releases",
         title = basename(csv_list[i]) # just file name, not whole path
    )

  #ggsave(filename = sub('\\.csv$', '.png', csv_list[i]), device = "png", plot = gg) # change file extension to indicate output format
  #message(file.path(png_csv_path, sub('\\.csv$', '.png', basename(csv_list[i]))))
  ggsave(filename = file.path(png_csv_path, sub('\\.csv$', '.png', basename(csv_list[i])), device ="png", plot = gg))
}
```

Comment: `?dir.create` function will create directory for you. You can use `paste0` to glue together paths and filenames (or use the `glue` package). The package `here` and its function `?here` should solve the navigation issues.

Comment: Hi @alongtest12! I am happy to see that the code I provided meanwhile seems to work for you! There is no need to delete a question once it is answered, though. Feel free to mark my reply here as the correct answer if it solves your problem remaining problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `path` in `list.files()` and return `full.names`:

```
csv_list = list.files(path="/full/path/to/codecov/", pattern="*.csv", full.names=T)
```

If the csv-files are located in subdirectories of that path also set `recursive=T`:

```
csv_list = list.files(path="/full/path/to/codecov/", pattern="*.csv", full.names=T, recursive=T)
```

Then create the output diretory:

```
img_path="/full/path/to/codecov/code_coverage_png"
dir.create(img_path)
```

Finally set the path of your output files to the new diretory:

```
ggsave(filename = file.path(img_path, sub('\\.csv$', '.jpeg', basename(csv_list[i])), plot = gg) # change file extension to indicate output format
```

Comment: I get this error `Error: `device` must be NULL, a string or a function.`

Comment: For which line?

Comment: This line:  ggsave(filename = file.path(img_path, sub('\\.csv$', '.jpeg', basename(csv_list[i])), plot = gg) # change file extension to indicate output format

Comment: Did you manage to save `.jpeg` files before? How exactly does your output file look like? Put a `message(file.path(img_path, sub('\\.csv$', '.jpeg', basename(csv_list[i])))`before the `ggsave()`to look at it.

Comment: Yes the file types were .png I don't know if that really matters anyway. But before I was able to save.

Comment: So what if you change the format from `.jpeg` to `.png`in the current command? If this works then the path is not the problem but the graphic device for `jpeg`on your machine. You could then ask a new question 'Why does `ggsave()` to jpeg not work on my machine?' providing details on your machine. The more precise your question is the better will be the answers.

Comment: It does show the path where the .png file goes but it still poduces that same message when I try to save them into the directory ```Error: `device` must be NULL, a string or a function.```

Comment: What happens if you specifiy the device directly as you did initially? I.e. add `device='jpeg'`to the `ggsave()`call.

Comment: lol same thing. I don't know what's wrong with this. ```ggsave(filename = file.path(png_csv_path, sub('\\.csv$', '.png', basename(csv_list[i])), device ="png", plot = gg)) ```

Comment: Can you show once more the output of `message(file.path(img_path, sub('\\.csv$', '.jpeg', basename(csv_list[i])))`? You can also specify a function for the device, i.e. `device=png()`. Then you can try to play with arguments to this function, e.g. set the `type` manually.

Comment: In your updated code you have a mistake in setting the brackets. Try `ggsave(filename = file.path(png_csv_path, sub('\\.csv$', '.png', basename(csv_list[i]))), device ="png", plot = gg)`

Comment: Agh it work! Thank you! Apologies for deleting the posts. One last question, The folder I create doesn't get created in the root directory but in the sub directory. How do I fix it so it goes into the root?

Comment: `img_path="/full/path/to/code_coverage_png"; dir.create(img_path)`